# nestjs uploader doesn't return path

Tags: file-upload, nestjs, multer

I have a table in database called documents, it needs to save file_name and path but when I send post request in swagger it gives error docs should not be empty

```
{
  "success": false,
  "code": 400,
  "data": null,
  "timestamp": "11.11.2023, 13:35:58",
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": [
      "docs should not be empty"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request"
  }
}
```

This is multer config

```
// Multer configuration
export const multerConfig = {
  dest: './uploadedDocs',
};

// Multer upload options
export const multerOptions = {
  // Enable file size limits
  limits: {
    fileSize: +10000000000000,
  },
  // Check the mimetypes to allow for upload
  fileFilter: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
    if (file.mimetype.match(/\/(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
      // Allow storage of file
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      // Reject file
      cb(new HttpException(`Unsupported file type ${extname(file.originalname)}`, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST), false);
    }
  },
  // Storage properties
  storage: diskStorage({
    // Destination storage path details
    destination: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
      const uploadPath = multerConfig.dest;
      // Create folder if doesn't exist
      if (!existsSync(uploadPath)) {
        mkdirSync(uploadPath);
      }
      cb(null, uploadPath);
    },
    // File modification details
    filename: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
      // Calling the callback passing the random name generated with the original extension name
      const filee = `${uuid()}${extname(file.originalname)}`;
      cb(null, filee);
      console.log(filee);
    },
  }),
};
```

This is controller

```
  //STUDENT documents

  @ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
  @ApiBody({
    schema: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        file_name: { type: 'string' },
        file: {
          type: 'string',
          format: 'binary',
        },
      },
    },
  })
  // @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('images', +100000, multerConfig))
  @DecoratorWrapper('Create Student Document', true, [Role.Rector, Role.Administrator, Role.Deen])
  @Post('createStudent-document/:id')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', multerOptions))
  async createDocs(
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
    @Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number,
    @Body() dto: CreateStudentDocumentsDto,
  ) {
    console.log(file);

    try {
      const result = await this.createDocument.createDocuments(file, id, dto);
      return CoreApiResponse.success(HttpStatus.OK, result);
    } catch (error) {
      return CoreApiResponse.error(error);
    }
  }
```

this is usecase(service) file

```
@Injectable()
export class CreateStudentDocumentUseCase {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(StudentDocuments)
    private readonly documentRepository: Repository<StudentDocuments>,
    @InjectRepository(Student)
    private readonly studentRepository: Repository<Student>,
  ) {}

  async createDocuments(file: any, id: number, dto: CreateStudentDocumentsDto) {
    try {
      const student = await this.studentRepository.findOne({ where: { id } });
      if (!student) {
        throw new HttpError({
          message: 'STUDENT_NOT_FOUND',
          statusCode: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
        });
      }

      const document = this.documentRepository.create({
        student: { id },
        file_name: dto.file_name,
        docs: file,
        // added_by: dto.added_by,
      });

      return await this.documentRepository.save(document);
    } catch (error) {
      HttpError(error);
    }
  }
}
```

It is saving the file to uploadedDocs folder but not returning path to save it to db. I have logged filee in multer and it gives the path but in total not giving path I guess cuz I need save path in docs coulmn in db